# Android SQLite - How to label names

Tags: android, sqlite

Im currently using SQLLite to handle my data. I have the column NAME and want to number names, which are equal, f.E. I can add the name `Boris`, but if I add `Boris` the second time, the first entry gets updated to `Boris 1`, while the second one gets number `Boris 2`.

My question is, how can I do the sql query, so that it selects every `Boris` entry, even if its numbered.

My current approach is:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT " + DealContract.PurchaseTable.COLUMN_NAME + " FROM " + DealContract.PurchaseTable.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DealContract.PurchaseTable.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE '" + name + "%'", null);
```

Simplfied:

```
SELECT NAME FROM PURCHASES WHERE NAME LIKE 'name%'
```

This works, but:

- doesn't exclude names with stuff added after it like `Boris Johnson`
- includes names with stuff missing like `Bori`

EDIT: Should be "How to number names"

Comment: Maybe replace "%" with "[1-9]"?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović is that only for one number? If yes, how would it look like with multiple numbers? And it also needs to select the name which isnt numbered

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you can extract results into Java, and then work from there? Like, some kind of cycle which would determine the name etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove the `%` wildcard.
Change `SELECT NAME FROM PURCHASES WHERE NAME LIKE 'name%'` to `SELECT NAME FROM PURCHASES WHERE  NAME LIKE  'name [0-9]'  OR NAME LIKE  'name'`.
If for example your query returns 1 result, you will know there is only 1 `boris` in the database. So simply get the number of rows returned, if its not zero, append that number to `boris` and save.